# Повторная передача данных в БД

Tags: jdbc, java

Есть простая форма с полями: Name, LastName, Login, Email, Password и таблица в БД с аналогичными полями. На форме есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую данные, введенные пользователем передаются в БД, затем значения полей на форме я очищаю (MainUsersForm.nameField.setText(null)), вроде бы все нормально, в БД по нажатию на кнопку записывается нужная информация, но при повторном нажатии на кнопку передаются те же данные, что и вводились в 1-й раз, а не обновленные. Я так полагаю, что надо обновлять как то память, подскажите новичку как :)

Строка для запроса внесения информации в БД выглядит следующим образом:

```
private static final String insertNewUser = "INSERT INTO mainusers (name, lastName, login, email, password) VALUES ('"+MainUsersForm.nameField.getText()+"', '"+MainUsersForm.lastnameField.getText()+"', '"+MainUsersForm.loginField.getText()+"', '"+MainUsersForm.emailField.getText()+"', '"+MainUsersForm.passwordField.getText()+"')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы определили константу притом статическую, ужс. [Атрибуты final и static](http://www.darkraha.com/rus/java/java16.php).

Comment: Ой, правда :D Спасибо, как то сразу не подумал, проблема решена)

Answer (score 0):

Строки в java не меняются после инициализации. Соответсвенно перед нажатием кнопки надо заново присваивать строке новые данные.